Is there an analytical function to normalize values in Oracle?
In the following example we have ten random values from 6 to 233 (or any other integer range).
Using common math we have, on last column, the values normalized from 0 to 1 (the usual range in this case).
col value format 999D99
col min_value like value
col max_value like value
col norm like value


WITH data
AS (
    SELECT rownum row#
        ,DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(6, 233) value
    FROM dual connect BY LEVEL <= 10
    )
SELECT row#
    ,value
    ,min(value) OVER () min_value   
    ,max(value) OVER () max_value
    ,(value - min(value) OVER ()) / (max(value) OVER () - min(value) OVER ()) norm
FROM data
/

The output (one of them of course) is:
        ROW#   VALUE MIN_VALUE MAX_VALUE    NORM
------------ ------- --------- --------- -------
           1   13.40     10.19    220.10    0.02
           2   53.78     10.19    220.10    0.21
           3   10.19     10.19    220.10    0.00
           4  115.37     10.19    220.10    0.50
           5  195.55     10.19    220.10    0.88
           6  202.47     10.19    220.10    0.92
           7   22.73     10.19    220.10    0.06
           8  204.35     10.19    220.10    0.92
           9   60.00     10.19    220.10    0.24
          10  220.10     10.19    220.10    1.00

I made this way because, to my suprise, there is no analytic function to easily perform this.
I was expecting that this function already exists, and the code would be something like:
WITH data
AS (
    SELECT rownum row#
        ,DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(6, 233) value
    FROM dual connect BY LEVEL <= 10
    )
SELECT row#
    ,value
    ,min(value) OVER () min_value   
    ,max(value) OVER () max_value
    ,normalize(value) OVER () norm
FROM data
/


